# Stop a Windows Task Scheduler task after a certain time

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to make a scheduled task stop after a set number of seconds?

What I want:

1. Run task every 5 minutes
2. Stop task after 30 seconds

So I can run a file then after the given time stop the task.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to schedule another task to kill whatever program you are running, something like Taskkill.  Here is the link to the Microsoft site on how to use TaskKill http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx.

I would question why you need to kill a program though, you should look for a method of having the program terminate itself when it needs to.

Comment: I wanted to start internet explorer with a link that starts a cron than terminate iexplore so it can start in 5 minutes

Comment: Then I would suggest scheduling your task as @MONZTAAA says, then scheduling a task to run TaskKill one minute later, unless having the browser open for more than 30 seconds is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The task must be configured in two steps.

First you create a simple task that start at 0:00, every day. Then, you go in Advanced... (or similar depending on the operating system you are on) and select the Repeat every X minutes option for 24 hours.

The key here is to find the advanced properties. If you are using the XP wizard, it will only offer you to launch the advanced dialog once you created the task.

Comment: So i cant set it for 30 seconds?

Comment: You cant do an interval less than a minute, you should try an external program to do the job.